# Ensure to run code after rails `delayed job` fails or successess

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Is there any way we can ensure certain code to run event after the `delayed job` is failed or succeeds just like we can write `ensure` block in exception handling?

Comment: Are you using a Job ? Or you are using it like `user.delay.send_email` ?

Comment: @LolWalid Yes I am using `.delay` to call the job method as you have specified.
`user.delay.send_email`

Comment: did you see my answer? why not put the `user.delay.send_email` into it's own method and use `ensure` there?

Comment: Actualty no you can't do this, you have to define a job that call send_email. Or write a method that ensure an action after the email has been sent and delay this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with the following approach?

```
def delayed_job_method
  do_the_job
ensure
 something
end
```

Comment: I thought this syntax works only for `begin-rescue` block. Still a newbie.
Will try your solution.. :)

Comment: @Swaps well, I've just given it a thought - my approach will ensure that something is done **immediately** after you enqueue the job, not after it succeeds or fails.